# How to animate a button that is created by another button KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

im quite new with KivyMD and can you guys help me on how to animate a button that is created by another button? like if i had clicked on a button from the FloatingActionSpeedDial button, it'll create another button, how can i animate its entry? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to your solution:

1. Creating the Button
2. Animating it

Now you typically create a using the `add_widget(Button)` method. This will add a button to the screen and internally add it to the parent widgets children.

What you'll then want to do is animate the button, which is done using the `Animation` module (see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html)

Now I don't know how you want to animate your button, as the possibilities are pretty much endless, but here is an example of some code that, when you press the button on the screen a new button is added and grows to the right size.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv = Builder.load_string(
    """
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        text: 'Add Button!'
        on_release: app.add_button()
"""
)


class MyMainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

    def add_button(self):
        """
        Function first creates a button of size [0, 0] and opacity 0 (invisible), then adds it to the screen. Next it 
        animates it so that the size is the same as the last button and the opacity is 1. 
        """
        last_button = self.root.children[-1]
        button = Button(
            size_hint=[0, 0],
            pos=[last_button.x + last_button.width/2, last_button.top + last_button.height/2],
            text='Added',
            opacity=0
        )
        self.root.add_widget(button)
        animation = Animation(size_hint=[0.3, 0.3], pos=[last_button.x, last_button.top], opacity=1)
        animation.start(button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```